# How to make responsive list based on screen size and number of li tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page what will be displayed on fullscreen mode. In this page, there is a `<ul>` with some `<li>` tags. They will be displayed in 3 columns fit on one screen without scrolling.

In the default case, the number of `<li>` tags will be 1 - 20, but sometimes it will be 20 - 24.

I need to make them responsive dependant on screen width and number of li tag, but I have no idea how to do this. I think my problem is how to change the font size and height of what in the `<li>`.

I think that I have to use javascript to handle this.

```css
#list {
  margin: 3% 0 0 2%;
}

#list li {
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3% 2% 3% 0;
  font-size: 4.375vw;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  border-bottom: 1px #BABABA solid;
}

#list li div.ph_img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 3% 0px 0px;
  width: 30%;
}

#list li div.ph_img img {
  width: 100%;
}

#list li span.position {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 1.4vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  margin: 0px;
}

#list li span.name {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 2vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  margin: 0px;
}

#list li span.floor {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  margin: 0px;
}

#list li span.floor em {
  color: #FF0000;
  font-style: normal;
  padding-left: 3%;
}

#list li span.green {
  float: right;
  width: 67%;
  background-color: #00923A;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 2vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

#list li span.red {
  float: right;
  width: 67%;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 2vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li class="clearfix">
    <div class="ph_img"><img src="xxxxxxxxxxx" alt=""></div>
    <span class="position">something 1</span>
    <span class="name">something 1</span>
    <span class="floor">something 1</span>
    <span class="status green" device-id="Z001">something 1</span>
  </li>
  <li class="clearfix">
    <div class="ph_img"><img src="xxxxxxxxxxx" alt=""></div>
    <span class="position">something 1</span>
    <span class="name">something 1</span>
    <span class="floor">something 1</span>
    <span class="status green" device-id="Z001">something 1</span>
  </li>
  <li class="clearfix">
    <div class="ph_img"><img src="xxxxxxxxxxx" alt=""></div>
    <span class="position">something 1</span>
    <span class="name">something 1</span>
    <span class="floor">something 1</span>
    <span class="status green" device-id="Z001">something 1</span>
  </li>
  <li class="clearfix">
    <div class="ph_img"><img src="xxxxxxxxxxx" alt=""></div>
    <span class="position">something 1</span>
    <span class="name">something 1</span>
    <span class="floor">something 1</span>
    <span class="status green" device-id="Z001">something 1</span>
  </li>
  <li class="clearfix">
    <div class="ph_img"><img src="xxxxxxxxxxx" alt=""></div>
    <span class="position">something 1</span>
    <span class="name">something 1</span>
    <span class="floor">something 1</span>
    <span class="status green" device-id="Z001">something 1</span>
  </li>
  <li class="clearfix">
    <div class="ph_img"><img src="xxxxxxxxxxx" alt=""></div>
    <span class="position">something 1</span>
    <span class="name">something 1</span>
    <span class="floor">something 1</span>
    <span class="status green" device-id="Z001">something 1</span>
  </li>
  <li class="clearfix">
    <div class="ph_img"><img src="xxxxxxxxxxx" alt=""></div>
    <span class="position">something 1</span>
    <span class="name">something 1</span>
    <span class="floor">something 1</span>
    <span class="status green" device-id="Z001">something 1</span>
  </li>
<ul>
```

Please help me some idea to handle this!

Comment: Javascript is the last thing to use for this. The best thing would be to write some [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) in your CSS which change the layout based on the available screen width

Comment: I think so. But have no idea how to calculate the font-size to make all <li> element in specific height size.